# PHP how to display the 5 most reccurent words in a list

Tags: php, string

I have a list in which the visited websites are stored (a thousand), and I need to display the TOP 5 Most Visited Websites :

```
$websites= "site#1.com site#2.com site#1.com site#1.com site#3.com ... "
```

Comment: Where did the list come from? The data should be available in a more countable source. If not, extra work (though not much) will be required.

Comment: What have you already tried? This site is meant to help you understand , not do it for you

Comment: I tried a lot of things but didn't work like using two loops

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: My god, just when I thought PHP couldn't get more pathetic in supplying ridiculous functions for basic two-line programming tasks, they implement `array_count_values`. Omfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is deliberately verbose so you understand what's going on:

```
<?php

$websites = "site#1.com site#2.com site#1.com site#1.com site#3.com";

//presuming they'll always be seperated by a single space...
$sites = explode(' ', $websites);

$siteCount = array();

foreach ($sites as $site) {
  if (!isset($siteCount[$site])) {
    $siteCount[$site] = 1;
  } else {
    $siteCount[$site]++;
  }
}

arsort($siteCount);

$finalArray = array_slice($siteCount, 0, 5);

var_dump($siteCount);
```

Which outputs:

```
array(3) {
  ["site#1.com"]=&gt;
  int(3)
  ["site#3.com"]=&gt;
  int(1)
  ["site#2.com"]=&gt;
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: yeah it works, so is there a way to manipulate the results so that I can display percentage in spite of int(x), knowing that I already have the total number of visited websites `$total`

Comment: Yes. Add the values up to get a total, then divide 100 by that total.

Comment: yeah I know but how you do it with an array ? if it were a simple variable it's would be more easy

Comment: you can loop through them again, adding them together

Comment: I'm not talking about the total because I already have it. I don't know what to change to have percentage , i tried ` echo ($sitecount*100)/$total.'%'`

Answer (score 2):

That's a string, so you have to convert it into an array:

```
$websites_array = explode(" ", $websites);
```

then you can get element frequencies with

```
$frequencies=array_count_values($websites_array)
$most_frequent_websites=array_keys($frequencies, max($frequencies))
```

the `array_count_values` returns a frequency map, `array_keys` find the key (website) associated to the maximum value.

Note that in case you have more than one website with the highest count, it will return an array of most frequent websites.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sites = explode(' ',$site_string);
$top5 = array_count_values($array);
rsort($top5);
$top5 = array_slice($top5, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution:

```
$websites= "site#1.com site#2.com site#1.com site#1.com site#3.com site#2.com";
$sites = explode(' ', $websites);
foreach($sites as $site)
    $visits[$site]++;

// Sort by descending number of visits
arsort($visits);  
var_dump($visits);
```

[Working sample](http://eval.in/29483).

Comment: but how can I instead of displaying int(x) display a percentage, knowing that I already have the total number ?

Answer (score -1):

We could do this that way :

```
$websites_array = explode(' ', $websites);

$top_websites = array_count_values($websites_array);

asort($top_websites);

// $top_websites = array('#site2' => 5, '#site4' => 4, '#site1' => 2, ...)
```

Comment: What do you think `asort` will return? It returns a boolean, not an array.